# How can I speed up the following code in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to think of a faster way to implement this code. Tried vectorizing the **init** of the glider object, but could not figure out how to pass in the multiple values or perform an action such as the move() function on each of the objects.

```
def myFunc(fairy_dust):

    for particle in fairy_dust:
        temp = glider(particle[0], particle[1], particle[2], particle[3])
        temp = temp.move()
        particle[0] = temp.x
        particle[1] = temp.y
        particle[2] = temp.heading
```

Comment: How do you know this is your bottleneck? Like, have you profiled your performance or are you still early on and looking to make this uber-performant? Because some here is going to pull out the "premature optimization is the root of all evil" quote.

Comment: Aside from parallelizing the for loop (e.g. processing half of the particles on thread A and half on thread B), you can't really do too much to make this noticeably faster. Try reducing the number of particles in `fairy_dust` :P

Comment: I think most of the overhead in that loop comes from creating a glider instance just to call its move method and then to copy its advanced state  out. I would inline the body of the move method into the loop.

Comment: I think we'd need a bit more context as to what glider does, and just calling the .move() method.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks! That was the route to go, I looked at what the move method was actually doing and did that math in myFunc using np, it seems to be working slightly faster now.